# How to create flow in C#

Tags: c#, office365api, power-automate

I have referred this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api link to create a flow programmatically,but when I use the Api in my C# code I am getting "Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://orgxxxxxx.crmx.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/workflows");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string str = "{\"properties\":{\"connectionReferences\":{\"shared_commondataservice\":{\"connectionName\":\"shared-commondataser-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004\",\"source\":\"Invoker\",\"id\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Power Apps/apis/shared_commondataservice\"}},\"definition\":{\"$schema\": \"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#\",\"contentVersion\": \"1.0.0.0\",\"parameters\": {\"$connections\": {\"defaultValue\": {},\"type\": \"Object\"},\"$authentication\": {\"defaultValue\": {},\"type\": \"SecureObject\"}},\"triggers\": {\"Recurrence\": {\"recurrence\": {\"frequency\": \"Minute\",\"interval\": 1},\"type\": \"Recurrence\"}},\"actions\": {\"List_records\": {\"runAfter\": {},\"metadata\": {\"flowSystemMetadata\": {\"swaggerOperationId\": \"GetItems_V2\"}},\"type\": \"ApiConnection\",\"inputs\": {\"host\": {\"api\": {\"runtimeUrl\": \"https://firstrelease-001.azure-apim.net/apim/commondataservice\"},\"connection\": {\"name\": \"@parameters('$connections')['shared_commondataservice']['connectionId']\"}},\"method\": \"get\",\"path\": \"/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default.cds'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('accounts'))}/items\",\"queries\": {\"$top\": 1},\"authentication\": \"@parameters('$authentication')\"}}},\"outputs\": {}}},\"schemaVersion\":\"1.0.0.0\"}";
            string json = "{" +
                 "\"category\": 5," +
                 "\"statecode\": 0 "+
                 "\"type\": 1," + 

                 "\"description\": \"This flow reads some data from Dataverse.\"," +
                 "\"primaryentity\":\"none\"," +
                 "\"clientdata\":"+  str +
                 "}";



        streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    }
```

Output:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Power Automate or Dynamics CRM, but *usually* you have to authenticate to use web services. I don't see any authentication logic in your code, and the error message seems to confirm that suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get 401 response its mean you are not send authorization header

this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth) will help you